# Find a product of cyclic groups of prime power order isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/1000000\mathbb{Z})^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

The group in the problem is the group of units $(\mathbb{Z}/1000000\mathbb{Z})^\times$

The answer gives $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2^4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5^5\mathbb{Z}$.

I've been reading about decompositions of groups into other groups and I'm just completely stumped and confused by all the different decomposition theorems. Could someone help me explain this (right now, very arbitrary looking) decomposition into its factors and the relevant theorems being applied here?

Comment: You can look up details in http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/lec07.pdf, especially section 7 and Proposition 6.1 and 4.1

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's just
$$(\Bbb Z/2^6\Bbb Z)^\times \times(\Bbb Z/5^6\Bbb Z)^\times.$$
For odd $p$, $(\Bbb Z/p^m\Bbb Z)^\times$ is always cyclic.
For $(\Bbb Z/2^m\Bbb Z)^\times$, see my previous reply.

Comment: This much I know - but the question is asking for a a decomposition into groups of prime power order.